# After placing an order the Customer's Account shows "You have placed no orders."

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, orders, guest-checkout

We are running `Magento 1.9.3.3 on Linux CENTOS 6.8 x86_64 standard – host  cPanel & WHM 64.0 (build 29);`

A customer placed an order on June 28, 2017 at 10:16:15 AM;

He received the confirmation E-mail and I see the order in the Admin Panel under Orders.  All of the detail appears to be there.  The order is being processed normally in our system. From our standpoint we see no problem.

I can find no errors in the logs at the time of the order. The customer complained that when he logs into his account and views My Orders, he sees the message "`You have placed no orders`". He did not make the purchase as a guest, I see his name and E-mail associated with the order.

How can I create the records or pointers to make his account display the order?

Answer (score 0):

Customers can place the order using an existing email address as a guest. 
Open order from the backend and check the Customer Group. It shouldn't be NOT LOGGED IN.
You can link the customer by updating the `customer_id` column in `sales_flat_order` table.